# Does memory allocated to JavaScript variables in a PhoneGap app go out of scope if the app is closed?

Tags: javascript, local-storage, phonegap, apache-cordova

For example if I declare:

```
var x = … // get result from some API
```

Will this result be available for use the next time I open the app or should I store it locally on the device ?

Comment: You have little or no control over app resources. If there's something you need, store it somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phonegap variable storage is not persistent. If you need to store value, consider using localStorage or a database